# How to create a objects with related tables

Tags: python, django

I'm building a django web app and I'm having troubles in inserting news objects(musics) without using forms.
I will give an example of what I've so far:

here is my models.py:

```
   from django.db import models
   from django.contrib.auth.models import User

   class Genre(models.Model):
      genre=models.CharField(max_length=250)
      
      def __str__(self):
         return str(self.genre)

   class Music(models.Model):
      author=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      genre=models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      title=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      audio_file=models.FileField(upload_to='songs/')
      cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='covers/')
```

and here is my views.py:

```
  from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from .models import *

  def add_song(request):
     if request.method=='post' or request.FILES:
        genre=request.post['genre']    #getting the genre data from html template
        title=request.post['title']    #getting the title from html template
        audio_file=request.files['audio_file']
        cover=request.files['cover']
        
        instance=request.user
        
        genre_selected=Genre.objects.get(genre=genre)  #to get the genres already inserted in the db

        music=Music.objects.create(author=instance, title=title, genre=genre_selected, audio_file=audio_file, cover=cover)
        return redirect('/')
     else:
       return render(request, 'music.html')
```

And when I try to add new always I get this error:
*Cannot assign "<Genre: Pop>": "Music.genre" must be a "Genre" instance.*

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: In your `def __str__` method in the `Genre` model, there's a typo. I think you mean `return str(self.genre)`

Comment: Exactly, I mean `return str(self.genre)`

Comment: Have you ran `py manage.py makemigrations` and `py manage.py migrate`?

Comment: But the error is not because of this. The error still remain.

Comment: @KwakuBiney yes I did